# How can I get frequency distribution for each element in lists in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the frequency distribution of the tags in this data frame.

[image]

the problem is each row contains a list of tags, not just one. hence, I can't use

```
df['Tags'].value_counts()
```

so How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pandas 0.25+ use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
s = df['Tags'].explode().value_counts()
```

Another solution with DataFrame constructor and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) working also for version under `0.25`:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(df['Tags'].tolist()).stack().value_counts()
```

---

Or is possible use pure python with `Counter` and flattening:

```
from collections import Counter

s = pd.Series(Counter([y for x in df['Tags'] for y in x]))
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tags':[['a','b'],['a','b','c'],['c','b','c'], ['c']]})
s = df['Tags'].explode().value_counts()
print(s)
c    4
b    3
a    2
Name: Tags, dtype: int64
```